# How to access child component node from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a feature to close a menu component when clicking outside of it. To achieve this I check if current target is present in ref node. The problem is when I click on Icon component... Inspecting it, e.target happens to be img from Icon component, and if I search it on ref.current, it's not present... Is there a way to link parent and child nodes together to achieve this condition ref.current.contains(e.target) when i click on a child component?

Parent component:

```
function Menu ({showMenu, close}) {
   const ref = useRef(null)
   useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside)

        return () =>{
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside)
        }
    }, [])

    function handleClickOutside(e) {
        if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target) && showMenu) {
            close()
        }
    }

    return (
      <div ref={ref}>
          <Icon action={openMenu2}/>
          <h1>Menu</h1>
      </div>
    )

}
```

Child

```
function Icon ({action}) {
    return (
        <div onClick={() => action()}>
            <i>
                <img src={imageSrc} alt="icon"></img>
            </i>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: not sure if i understand what you want.. if you click on Icon div, you want to close/hide Menu component? Also, what does this close() function do?

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto i've updated it, actually icons changes type of content on menu component. Close functions, closes Menu component

Answer (score 0):

if u just want to use child Component's ref , u can pass ref to props.action

```
//Child

const cRef = useRef(null)

function Icon ({action}) {
    return (
        <div ref= onClick={() => action(cRef)}>
            <i>
                <img src={imageSrc} alt="icon"></img>
            </i>
        </div>
    )
}
```

then u can use it in parent Component

or u can move those logic to child component

> To achieve this I check if current target is present in ref node. The problem is when I click on Icon component... Inspecting it, e.target happens to be img from Icon component, and if I search it on ref.current, it's not present...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass menu toggle function directly to down children to children,

Toggle Function

With this approach you don't need to check if showMenu is true because
this function will close the menu if it is open, and it will open if it is close

Assuming your state is at the parent of Menu component

```
 const toggleMenu = () => {
    setMenuOpen(!menuOpen);
  };
```

Then in Menu component pass menuOpen as menu's state and toggleMenu as function to change it.

```
function Menu({ toggleMenu, menuOpen }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Icon toggleMenu={toggleMenu} />
      <h1>Menu : {`${menuOpen ? "open" : "closed"} in Menu component`}</h1>
    </div>
  );



}
```

And in Icon component you can toggle the menu

```
function Icon({ toggleMenu }) {
  return (
    <div onClick={toggleMenu}>
      <img
        style={{ width: 35, cursor: "pointer" }}
        alt="hamburger-menu"
        src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default Icon;
```

In action on codesandbox :https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-joliot-zb3t7?file=/src/Menu.jsx:54-299

If your app is getting complicated with passing states and passing state change functions I recommend you to check redux pattern.

Here link for redux : https://react-redux.js.org/